# Automatically insert a space in some C expressions

Tags: whitespace, c

The corporate rules about indention forces us to surround our `if` conditions with spaces like this (in a C and C++ codebase) :

```
 if (<space>foo == bar<space>)
 {
 }
```

Is there any emacs tool to insert them automatically?

Comment: I'm not aware of any function in Emacs that can help you with this, but you should be able to use astyle with the --pad-header option to accomplish what you want. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801983/how-do-i-use-astyle-within-emacs) might help.

Comment: such changes 1) should have been incorporated when you wrote the code.  and 2) can be easily performed globally via a simple `find and replace` operation.

Comment: Or run clang-format from a hook before you save.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** not a full answer, but may help.

I don't know about a tool… the main challenge seems to be capturing `X` in occurrences of `if (X)`. The tricky thing is that you can't just search for a regular expression and be done: `X` has to have balanced parenthesis. Easy? Not so fast: parenthesis do not need to be balanced if they are

- inside of strings `"asd)"`;
- in a char `')'`; or
- inside of a comment.

I think these might be the only cases that matter. **Assuming there is no macro trickery in your codebase!** Our recipe would then be

1. Scan until `if[:space:]*([:space:]*`
2. Replace the next occurrence of `[:space:]*([:space:]*` by a `(` (parenthesis surrounded by spaces),
3. move the cursor forwards, and continue so long as you have not found a closing parenthesis matching the first one (i.e., balancing the first one), skipping strings and comments. The key point here is to save the position whenever you transition from non-space to space character.
4. Save the position of the matching `)`.

At this point we have

```
      ... if ( balanced-parenthesis-exp)    )
                                        ^   ^
                                        |   |
                                        |  closing par (b)
                                        | 
                                     end of condition (a)
```

To conclude,

4. Replace what's between (a) and (b) by `)` (space followed by parenthesis)

This should be enough to get you started!

Answer (score 0):

I would use `replace-regexp` the forward space is easy use `M-X RET replace-regexp RET if<space>( RET if<space>(<space>`. You could use a similar replace-regexp rule to do the second space. For the second space, you would probably have to use several replace-regexp rules depending on what character your second variable ends with.