# automatic indentation with space like visual studio

Tags: indentation, package, whitespace

Is there any package that covers indentation with space like visual studio?

like,

```
if(a==b)  ==> if(a<space>==<space>b)

for(int i=0;i<N;i++) ==> for(int i<space>=<space>0;<space>i<space><<space>N;<space>i++)
```

similar question is already asked but it was uploaded almost 2 years ago, then I re-ask it. ([Automatically insert a space in some C expressions](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35534/automatically-insert-a-space-in-some-c-expressions))

thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [electric-operator](https://github.com/davidshepherd7/electric-operator) - minor mode to automatically add spacing around operators

Comment: Is there any package similar to this? This package can generate space while typing. but I want to add spaces whenever I do indentation.